# How do I handle a form button's POST request in Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, post, express, heroku

How do I submit a post request for multiple form fields using a button?

I'm trying to create a login page where the user clicks a single button to submit their email and password. I'm using Heroku with Node.js and Express.

I'm receiving the following error message when i try and run the app

[image: I'm receiving this error message when i try and run the app]

login.ejs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/login.css" />
 <div class="wrapper">
<form class="form-signin">       
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>      
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>   
</form>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('form-signin', function(request, response){    
    console.log(request.query.email);
    console.log(request.query.password);  
}

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/index')
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I believe the problem has to do with the following line in index.js:

```
app.post('form-signin', function(request, response){    
    console.log(request.query.email);
    console.log(request.query.password);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is literally spelled out for you in the error message you received.

In index.js, go to line 17 and add a `);` after the `}`

```
app.post('form-signin', function(request, response){    
    console.log(request.query.email);
    console.log(request.query.password);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message says you are missing a closing brace. So to solve that add another ')' at the end of the piece of code :

```
app.post('form-signin', function(request, response){    
console.log(request.query.email);
console.log(request.query.password);  
}); // <---- Notice the missing brace
```